# How can I set the margin/padding of the text displayed on an SWT Button?

Tags: java, swt

How can I set the margin/padding of the text displayed on an [SWT Button](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Button.html)?

```
Button b = new Button(parent, SWT.LEFT);
b.setText("Click me");
```

I got:

```
+-----------------+
|Click me         |
+-----------------+
```

I want (notice the space to the left):

```
+-----------------+
| Click me        |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: I don'T know if that is possible. Another possibility would be to make the button bigger. the text will remain at the same size but in another position. Does it work for you?

Comment: Do you just want to add a little padding or want to make the text center or right aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding is not supported for `Button`. The standard solutions are to either use `SWT.CENTER` or alternatively add a space to the start of the label...